# Can't generate a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, regular-language

I'm trying to generate a regular expression to detect any string that :

- Starts with the [
- Ends with ]
- Contains any word or number or space

Example : [Maxsens8 Innovations]

I'm using : https://regex101.com

I create this regular expression : `^\[[a-zA-Z0-9\]]$`

[image]

[image]

This regular expression does not match to expressions that i'm looking for and i thing the problem

is about the last character .

I will be gratefull if someone explain to me how to generate the right regular expression that

detect strings like : [Maxsens Innovations] [Verifik8] [Divoluci] ...

Comment: You have escaped the wrong closing square bracket `\]]$` (It's possible to not escape it at all, `]` is not a special character outside of a character class), the space is missing in your character class, and there's no quantifier.

Comment: thank you, how and where should i add the space in my regular expression ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`^\[[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*\]$` or
`^\[[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*\]$`

- `\]$` Match `]` followed by end of line (`$`)
- `[` and `]` are meta-characters hence should be escaped.
- Use `\s` to match any white-space char (including `newline`) or single `space`.

Note: This shall match against single input line. If you have multiple fragments per line then skip the line start and end markers viz., `^` and `$`.

Comment: Your pattern works but: Even if `]` is used to close a character class, it isn't a metacharacter, you don't have to escape it outside of a character class (in your pattern the backslash is simply ignored and doesn't cause any error). Also there's no reason to use a non-greedy quantifier here because the closing square bracket is not in the character class. That means that a the quantifier can blindly eat characters included in the set without to have to test if the next character is a closing square bracket, so a greedy quantifier is better suited.

Comment: Metacharacters outside of character classes are: `| \ . * + ? ^ $ ( ) { [` (note that there isn't the closing curly bracket too but the closing parenthesis is here. Also, in most unambigous situations, the opening curly bracket doesn't even need to be escaped).

Comment: I have kept the `\]`  outside of the `()*` quantifier as this is somewhat mandatory part of string. And regarding the non-greedy quantifiers, yes those are not required. It should be greedy till first `\]` is found.

Comment: what if my expression is :  [Maxsens Innovations] some text  ?

Comment: Should i remove the $ ?  or i have to add regular expression ?